# Div visibility toggle not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm making a tree structure using html and css. 
This is the final structure that I should reach: http://jsfiddle.net/yrE7N/1/

What I need is, on clicking a node, its children node will appear.

I've done this till now:

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZTkLg/11/

I've used this JS function

```
var _hidediv = null;
    function showdiv(id) {
    if(_hidediv)
        _hidediv();
    var div = document.getElementById(id);
    div.style.display = 'block';
    _hidediv = function () { div.style.display = 'none'; };
}
```

The thing is, the JS function doesn't seem to be toggling the visibility of the div `stage-two`.

I've used this function before on this page: http://leonardorestaurant.in/menu and it worked but I can't figure the problem out in this case.

Comment: One issue I see with the second fiddle is that `showdiv(two)` isn't passing text, it'll pass a variable that doesn't exist. Use `'two'` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<a href=# onclick="showdiv('two');">Some text here</a>
```

and

```
var flag = true;
function showdiv(id) {
    var div = document.getElementById(id);
    div.style.display = flag ? 'none' : 'block';
    flag = !flag;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/522LX/)

Comment: Put some quotes around that `href` attribute.

Comment: I added `display: none;' to `stage-two`. The fiddle still works but it requires two click to display the div. Any idea why?

Comment: @Siddharth then set `var flag = false;`

Comment: I'd prefer to remove the dependency on an external var if you can (and you can by using the `div.id.display` value to check for the state to switch to.  See my solution.

Answer (score 0):

The console in my browser prints out :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
```

Which means that here :

```
div.style.display = 'block';
```

div is not the result you think it should be...  That tells us that id is not what we think here :

```
var div = document.getElementById(id);
```

Which I confirmed by using :

```
console.log(id);
```

inside your function.

The id value is actually the `<div id="two">`

So, basically you already have the element you're looking for.

However, you've got bigger problems, which is that you need a toggle function, I'm just guessing.  Try using this :

```
function toggleDiv(id) {
    var el = document.getElementById(id);
    var newDisplayValue = "none";
    if ( el.style.display && el.style.display === "none" ) {
        newDisplayValue = "block";
    }
    el.style.display = newDisplayValue;
}
```

and change to this :

```
<a href=# onclick="toggleDiv('two');">
```

see it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5PGv9/)